# Rendering tier 0 despite the DirectX 9.0 installed (Asus ET1602)

Tags: rendering, wpf, gma

I have an Asus EeeTop PC ET1602 with integrated graphics Intel GMA 950 which supports DirectX 9. Despite the fact that DirectX 9 **is** installed, WPF is running *at tier 0*. Regarding to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx) it should run *at least at tier 1*. Do you have any idea why it does not?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_950):

> The GMA 950 shares the same architectural weakness as the GMA 900 no hardware geometry processing. Neither basic hardware transform and lighting, nor more advanced vertex shaders are handled in the GMA hardware.

And MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx):

> #### Rendering Tier 0
>
> A rendering tier value of 0 means that there is no graphics hardware acceleration available for the application on the device. At this tier level, developers should assume that all graphics will be rendered by software with no hardware acceleration. This tier's functionality corresponds to a DirectX version that is less than 9.0.

So for this card there is no hardware acceleration, the Direct X may be installed, but it's features will not be available.